# Pre-made PCB to drop: 12V->6V

Tags: power-supply, power, power-dissipation

I am using [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1723815.pdf) pre-made PCB in order to bring my 12V power supply to 6V. On the datasheet, it is claimed that the efficiency is about 90% (hence I expected low heat dissipation). With great surprise when I plugged everything together, I've noticed that the PCB heats up quite a bit. I haven't much experience with these things and therefore I would like to know if you'd expect it to heat a lot or not.
I am scared that something is wrong.

Comment: How much current are you drawing?  How hot?  Can you hold your finger on it indefinitely?  Does it boil water?

Comment: Right, i forgot to add:

Comment: Right, i forgot to add: with no load I have 20-30 mA and about the heat... After 3-4 minutes, if I put my finger on it for 4-5 seconds I start to feel it a bit painful, but still possible to hold my finger on it :).

Comment: If it's not shutting itself down, then I wouldn't worry about it. According to the datasheet it has thermal overload protection.

Comment: But how can it heat so much with an efficiency of over 90%? Is it because I have no load? Do you suggest adding a small heat sink?

Comment: 12 V at 30 mA is 0.36 watts and, depending on how big it is it might get fairly hot. How warm does it get under full load conditions is the clincher for me. In fact the data sheeet suggests that no-load current is 80mA so that's nearly 1 watt converted to heat.

Comment: If you're really worried about the heat, get a (DMM with a) thermocouple and actually measure the temperature. My estimate based on your fingering is below 65C, which is quite alright, although you need to derate the power rather conservatively if can't measure actual temp (see datasheet for derating).

Comment: Well, looking at the datasheet more closely, there's no derating for this device. However the ~0.36W idle dissipation is usually noticeable on a small device. Try connecting a 400-500 ohm resistor (make sure it's at least 1/2 Watt capable) directly across your 12V power supply and put your finger on that for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

It states on the front page that efficiency is 93%. It also states that you can use it to supply 3A. That means an 18 watt load if you have the output set for 6 volts. A 7% "inefficiency" is about 1.3 watts and given its small size it will get quite warm.

If you have a genuine 30mA flowing into it from the incoming 12V supply then the actual no-load power is only 0.36 watts so, my advice is to expect it to get a bit warmer under full load conditions and make sure you can provide natural convection to remove heat (see graph at top of page 5 of data sheet).

Comment: I don't understand what the derating graph is telling... How can i properly choose an heat sink?

Comment: @Worldsheep I wouldn't be happy with what they say in the data sheet. There are words towards the end of the document that don't really tie in with the graph on page 5. Nothing direct is mentioned about heatsinking. It's nice to find a to220 type regulator that replaces a LM78xx linear type but I suspect you might fair better with a different device with an external inductor. I believe Rohm make some that look useful.

Comment: I first tried to build by own DC/DC converter using a buck step down converter and it didn't heat up as much as this one. The problem was that I am testing on a breadbord and it was very unstable. Finally I had to give up and buy a pre-made module... Wouldn't a device with external inductor cause a similar instability issue? I'll have a look at Rohm! But in your opinion, are there solutions that heat less?

Comment: There are plenty of solution that heat less. Linear tech and TI spring to mind. I would encourage you to design a small PCB to overcome your breadboard issues. You can always post the PCB design here on SE and get opinions about if there are any potential layout problems.

Comment: The main issue is not the layout which is provided with the datasheet, but the time needed to design it and then produce it just to test it :). That's why I went for a pre-made :/

Comment: Do you need a 3A output? Can you split the load?

Comment: It is better if I have a 3A output, but I could consider using 1A outputs